e.getVersion is not a function BRAINTREE / incompatible version
I updated braintree and I have this issue
braintree.dropin.create({

      authorization:options.authorization,
      container: '#dropin-container',
      paypal: options.paypal,
      venmo: options.venmo,
      googlePay: options.googlePay,
      applePay: options.applePayConfig,
      samsungPay: options.samsungPay,
      dataCollector: options.dataCollector,
      card: {
        overrides: {
          fields: {
            postalCode: null
          }
        },
        vault: {
          vaultCard: false
        }
      }

and this is still giving us two issues (I think related with each other) even when I update all the links to the new version

I used this docs:
https://developer.paypal.com/braintree/docs/start/hello-client/javascript/v3/
